# Latch generated when attempting to create a memory bus in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I have been trying to attempt to create a simple memory in the FPGA that I can write to using another processor. I know I should use the FPGA RAM but somebody told me that I can make a simple register just using this code below:

```
vcap_data_store : process(resetb,clk)
begin
    if resetb = '0' then
        vcap_data_in11 <= "0000000000000000000000";
        vcap_data_in12 <= "0000000000000000000000";
        vcap_data_in13 <= "0000000000000000000000";
        vcap_data_in14 <= "0000000000000000000000";
    elsif (rising_edge(clk)) then
        vcap_data_in11 <= vcap_data_in_11;
        vcap_data_in12 <= vcap_data_in_12;
        vcap_data_in13 <= vcap_data_in_13;
        vcap_data_in14 <= vcap_data_in_14;
    end if;
end process;

vdi_input_gen : process(vdi_csb, vdi_wrb, vdi_indt)
begin

    if (vdi_csb = '0' and vdi_wrb = '0') then
        if vdi_addr = "00000" then
            vcap_data_in_11(15 downto 0) <= vdi_indt(15 downto 0);
        elsif vdi_addr = "00001" then
            vcap_data_in_11(21 downto 16) <= vdi_indt(5 downto 0);
        elsif vdi_addr = "00010" then
            vcap_data_in_12(15 downto 0) <= vdi_indt(15 downto 0);
        elsif vdi_addr = "00011" then
            vcap_data_in_12(21 downto 16) <= vdi_indt(5 downto 0);
        elsif vdi_addr = "00100" then
            vcap_data_in_13(15 downto 0) <= vdi_indt(15 downto 0);
        elsif vdi_addr = "00101" then
            vcap_data_in_13(21 downto 16) <= vdi_indt(5 downto 0);
        elsif vdi_addr = "00110" then
            vcap_data_in_14(15 downto 0) <= vdi_indt(15 downto 0);
        elsif vdi_addr = "00111" then
            vcap_data_in_14(21 downto 16) <= vdi_indt(5 downto 0);
                    end if;
    end if;

end process;
```

The thing is that I kept on getting these errors:

```
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <vcap_data_in_11_7>. Latches may be
generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches
in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
```

I don't want to use latches, but I don't know how to turn these into registers.
FYI I use the "buffer" type for the `vcap_data_in11`.

Is there any workaround to implement these as registers?

I'm quite new to VHDL, although I know 1 of the 10 commandments of VDHL "Thou shalt use registers, never latches", so I want to solve this warning.

It would be great if you can show me the way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have two separate recommendations.  The first fixes your code as it is.  The second (recommended) proposes a better way to structure the code for this problem

The first, the following will fix your code as it is, but is not the best answer.  The problem is because second process does not define what the signals vcap_data_in_11, ... get when they are not selected.  The quick answer is to use default assignments.  Note, the code is hard to read since you picked names that are too similar.

```
vdi_input_gen : process(vdi_csb, vdi_wrb, vdi_indt)
begin
   -- default assignments:
   vcap_data_in_11 <= vcap_data_in11 ;   -- tempQ <= Q;
   vcap_data_in_12 <= vcap_data_in12 ; 
   vcap_data_in_13 <= vcap_data_in13 ; 
   vcap_data_in_14 <= vcap_data_in14 ; 

   -- your other code goes here:
    if (vdi_csb = '0' and vdi_wrb = '0') then
        if vdi_addr = "00000" then
            vcap_data_in_11(15 downto 0) <= vdi_indt(15 downto 0);
        elsif vdi_addr = "00001" then
            vcap_data_in_11(21 downto 16) <= vdi_indt(5 downto 0);
        elsif vdi_addr = "00010" then
    . . . 

    end if;
end process;
```

My bigger recommendation is to re-write your code into a **single** process.  Surprised I am the first to recommend this as others feel strongly about this and I actually don't.  My main concern is about writing simple, readable code.  I also recommend that you use a case statement rather than if when processing the same object (in this case vdi_addr):

Hence, your code becomes the following.  Note you no longer need a default assignment because in a clocked process, the feedback becomes a load enable condition (which is required for this problem) rather than a latch.

```
vcap_data_store : process(resetb,clk)
begin
    if resetb = '0' then
        vcap_data_in11 <= "0000000000000000000000";
        vcap_data_in12 <= "0000000000000000000000";
        vcap_data_in13 <= "0000000000000000000000";
        vcap_data_in14 <= "0000000000000000000000";
    elsif (rising_edge(clk)) then
      if (vdi_csb = '0' and vdi_wrb = '0') then
        case vdi_addr is
          when "00000" =>   vcap_data_in11(15 downto 0)  <= vdi_indt(15 downto 0);
          when "00001" =>   vcap_data_in11(21 downto 16) <= vdi_indt( 5 downto 0);
          when "00010" =>   vcap_data_in12(15 downto 0)  <= vdi_indt(15 downto 0);
          when "00011" =>   vcap_data_in12(21 downto 16) <= vdi_indt( 5 downto 0);
          when "00100" =>   vcap_data_in13(15 downto 0)  <= vdi_indt(15 downto 0);
          when "00101" =>   vcap_data_in13(21 downto 16) <= vdi_indt( 5 downto 0);
          when "00110" =>   vcap_data_in14(15 downto 0)  <= vdi_indt(15 downto 0);
          when "00111" =>   vcap_data_in14(21 downto 16) <= vdi_indt( 5 downto 0);
          when others  =>   null ; -- do nothing !
        end case;
      end if;
    end if;
end process;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you described is asynchronous logic. You are missing a Clock. For beginning, a good start is to describe a sequential process, where all the registers are updated, and a asynchronous part, where the logic happens. Have a look at  [this link.](http://www.doulos.com/knowhow/vhdl_designers_guide/tips/sequential_processes/)
The important segments:
    -- signals
    signal Q, tempQ : ;

```
process (Clock, Reset)
begin
  if Reset = '0' then
    -- reset register, Q <= <init state>
  elsif rising_edge(Clock) then
    -- update Register, Q <= tempQ;
 end if;
end process;

process(sig1,sig2,...,sign)
  -- set tempQ <= func(input signals)
end process;
```

This will ensure that you are generating Registers if done correctly. Of course, you could merge these two processes into a single process, but In my opinion this will just make it harder to understand what's going on.

Comment: Prefer `...elsif rising_edge(Clock) then ...` but this is the answer.

Comment: Yes. Would use the same. Just copied the example from the link :). But thanks for the comment, I'll replace it

Comment: Unfortunately I am now getting that latch error on the tempQ instead, am I missing something?

What signal should I use in the sensitivity list sig1 sig2? Input signals? I used that cs and wr signal.

And what do you mean by the func(input signals)? Can't i drive a pin directly there? I mean that vdi_indt I used is a signal driven directly from the input pin as in std_logic_vector. Is this illegal?

Comment: can you edit your question and update your code? In most cases latches are a result of missing signals in the process sensitivity list or missing assignment of default values.

Comment: @Fajar As i thought: vcap_data_in_xx do not get a value in every case. A combinatorical process has to generate an output for every possible input -> This means that your vcap_data_in_xx signals have to be filled with a new value in any instance the process is running. An common solution to this is to assign '0' to them at the beginning of the process.

Comment: I managed to solve it using a workaround. It needs more time to finish the process but I can implement it using register and also retain the data when the address doesn't match. Not sure if this is a good implementation but I've learned a lot. Thanks Matthias!